# É errado Métodos mostrar algo para o usuário?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Bom estou começando agora na área de poo, vi em uma aula em que estou assistindo pelo youtube que era errado Métodos escreverem algo na tela, e como eu faria para mostrar se algo de errado acontecesse em uma determinada ação que o usuário fizesse.

Exemplo Aumentar o volume de um controle de televisão

```
public void aumentar() {
 int resultado = this.getVolume() + 1;
  if(resultado > 10){
    System.out.println("Você aumentou mais do que o permitido")
  }
  else{
    this.getVolume(setVolume+1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Errado não é, mas exibir de qualquer jeito pode ser. Esse caso seu é bem superficial para sugerir o que é "correto", mas se observar nos televisores atuais, eles mostram indicativos de volume quando voce aumenta ou reduz, alguns simplesmente monstram a barra vazia quando sem volume ou a barra toda cheia quando em volume alto. Nenhuma mensagem textual foi necessaria.

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é que nem todo tipo de mensagem precisa ser um texto ou um alerta. As vezes sinais ou figuras funcionam melhor.

Comment: Acho que uma ideia melhor é dizer que métodos devem restringir ao mínimo mensagens ao usuário, somente o necessário. Dizer que é errado... é errado. Nada é absoluto.

Comment: No meu exemplo que eu citei, em vez de mostrar algo para o usuário eu poderia fazer this,setVolume(10) , 10 no caso como fosse o volume máximo ?

Comment: Em vez de você dizer ao usuário que ele aumentou mais do que o permitido, por que não simplesmente setar um valor máximo de volume e, uma vez que esse valor seja atingido, é só não aumentar mais o volume? É o que acontece na vida real com TVs, né?

Comment: Pensando especificamente em TVs, acho que a maioria simplesmente não faz nada quando atinge-se o volume máximo. Você poderia então fazer `if (this.getVolume() < 10) {  aumenta }` - quando o volume for >= 10, não faz nada. Mas tudo depende do que for definido, vai que algum gerente de produto quer que seja mostrada alguma mensagem, sei lá

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: Sem saber o contexto da afirmação, o que podemos fazer é especular. Eu, por exemplo, acredito que o erro está no fato do [método fazer mais de uma coisa do que seu nome indica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Eu esperaria que um método chamado `aumentar` somente aumentasse o som. Talvez no máximo retornar um valor ou lançar uma exceção indicando que a operação falhou. A partir daí, se um feedback visual for necessário, não é mais responsabilidade deste método.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É "*errado*" usar qualquer tipo de saída que demonstre o que tem no seu sistema, como um `printStackTrace` por exemplo. Porque, além de a tela ficar bagunçada, feia e o usuário não entender nada, alguém mais entendido pode ver os nomes de classes, métodos, e dependendo do caso até versão e tipo de servidor que se está usando, o que é uma falha de segurança.

`System.out` não é recomendável porque ele vai ser impresso na ***saída padrão*** da aplicação, e essa saída muitas vezes é desconsiderada ou mesmo desativada. Se você fizer um `java -jar app.jar &` ou rodar a aplicação como `serviço`, essa saída já não vai existir mais.

Se você está fazendo uma aplicação WEB, ou algo complexo, o ideal é fazer um LOG com o erro **e** alertar o usuário com alguma mensagem tratada, e se possível um código, tipo um alert do javascript mesmo.

Para um método `main` básico, o System.out é OK, desde que as mensagens sejam tratadas e você não deixe um `stackTrace` passar.

Uma melhor tratativa seria utilizar LOGS, como **log4j** por exemplo, e usar funções como `log.error("Mensagem", Exception)` ou `log.warn()` ou `log.info()`, etç, dependendo do que deseja logar.